# Scrolling/viewing through a large amount of individual graphs in Databricks?

Tags: databricks, visualization

I have a dataset which consist of `Date`, `Value` and `Attribute`. I would like to plot value over time per attribute and then easily view them for example by scrolling/clicking the right arrow or similar.

When I use the visualisation tool in databricks it tries creating all lines into one plot and there is a message "`To improve performance, not all data has been shown. To reduce the amount of data, consider filtering or aggregating`".

It only shows me ~25 of my 150 attributes and all are already selected. Ideally it would generate the graph with all 150 attributes, but only the first selected and when I click the second the first is unselected and so on.

I know I can create the graphs using Python/R and then access each one using [0], [1] but I find it tedious.